# Mix different font sizes/faces in plot caption

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the code below to generate a heat map in R. It works well. The first section is the metric that I use to color the map. My question is how would I have the caption read like below. I know that one would put the first line in front of the other in the section that begins with caption = Paste ("Source...")However, how to have the first line be bigger and bold font is escaping me.

[image: Current Result]

```
 map50<- merge(us50, pop1)

 breaks <- seq(-.01, .05, by = .01)
 map50$c1<- cut(map50$growth, breaks, label=c("-1% to 0%", "0% to 1%", "1% 
 to 2%", "2% to 3%", "3% to 4%","4% to 5%"))


library(ggplot2)
b= ggplot(data= map50, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))
d= b+geom_polygon(aes(fill=c1), 
colour=alpha("black"),size=.05)+scale_fill_brewer(palette="YlOrRd",name="y/y 
growth rates")+coord_equal()
d= d+labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL,
title = "Average Employment Growth By State Q3 2018",
subtitle = "For Private, All Industries",
caption = paste("Source: BLS Quarterly Census of Employment and 
Wages\nProduced By: @NVlabormarket"))
d= d+theme_void()
d=d+theme(text = element_text(family = "NimbusSan", size = 10),
plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.25), "in"),
panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "#cccccc"),
legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
legend.position=c(.93, 0.2))
ggsave("Q32018EmploymentGrowthHeat-YlOrRdu.pdf")
```

Comment: Welcome! It would help dissect your problem if your R code was properly formatted. It's really important to follow a [style guide](https://style.tidyverse.org/). It also helps if your code was created as a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/), as we can't really help if we can't run the code ourselves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can plot first caption (bold line) using `caption` argument and second line using `tag` argument in `labs` function. Next you have to manually specify tag position using `plot.tag.position`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + 
    geom_point() +
    labs(caption = "Source: BLS Quarterly Census of Employment and Wages",
         tag = "Produced By: @NVlabormarket") +
    theme(plot.caption = element_text(vjust = 4, size = 9, face = "bold"),
          plot.tag = element_text(size = 9),
          plot.tag.position = c(0.89, 0))
```

[image]